# Using grep to check usernames

Tags: php, regex, grep

I search a `grep` command to check usernames like:-

```
mi.ma
ab-bc
ab.bc-ad
ab_de
mima
```

Not allowed should be:

```
..mima
mima..
mia--bc
mia---ad
ab___de
__ab
ab__
```

Allowed should be `a-z, 0-9, -, ., _` but not double `-, ., _` and this also not in front or end. And it must min. have 3 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
^[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-]?[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR6eM3/1)

Explanation:

- The first `[a-z0-9]+` ensures the user name STARTS with a (lower case) letter or number.
- `[._-]?` allows the presence of **one** (or none) `"."`, `"_"` or `"-"` character.
- The final `[a-z0-9]+` ensures the user name ENDS with a (lower case) letter or number.
- Wrapping this second group in `(...)*` allows for multiple `"."`, `"_"` or `"-"` characters in the middle of the user name (so long as they are separated by letters/numbers), e.g. `"ab.bc-ad"`.

**Edit:**

I just noticed your final condition for matching:

> And it must min. have 3 characters.

The easiest way to add this as part of the regex is with a lookahead - i.e.:

```
^(?=.{3,})[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-]?[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

Here is an [updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/hR6eM3/2) with additional test strings.

**Edit2:**

The above is perfectly valid for `PHP`. However, in case anyone reading this is actually looking for an answer using `grep` (i.e. nothing to do with `PHP`...)

First note that you can use the `-x` modifier to match an exact string, and therefore do away with the `^` and `$` anchors. You then have two options to make this work:

1. Use the above code with `grep -P`, or equivalently `pcregrep`, since the standard `grep` tool does not support lookaheads:

   ```
   pcregrep -x "(?=.{3,})[a-z0-9]+([._-]?[a-z0-9]+)*" <filename>
   ```
2. Use `grep -E`, or equivalently `egrep`, for the special character support; pipe the output through a second `grep` to satisfy the "min 3 chars" condition:

   ```
   egrep -x "[a-z0-9]+([._-]?[a-z0-9]+)*" <filename> | grep ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@TomLord answer is correct.

I indipendently came to exactly the same answer (a minute later :-(), but for PHP (since you added `php` tag...), so I write it, too...:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-]?[a-z0-9]+)*$/', $name);
```